# Trying to install "Ubuntu Base" in Vmware but getting a kernel panic!

Tags: 20.04

Here is how I install Ubuntu Base in Vmware:

```
load the live media
sudo passwd root
su root

parted -a optimal /dev/sda

* mklabel gpt
* print
* remove remaining partitions.(if there are any).
* unit mib
* mkpart primary 1 512
* name 1 boot
* set 1 boot on
* mkpart primary 512 -1
* name 2 rootfs
* print
* quit

mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda1
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2

mount /dev/sda2 /mnt

tar xvfz ubuntu-base-20.04.1-base-amd64.tar.gz -C /mnt

cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf

mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev

chroot /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /boot

apt-get update 
apt-get install --no-install-recommends grub-efi
apt-get install --no-install-recommends linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic
apt-get install --no-install-recommends initramfs-tools
apt-get install --no-install-recommends nano

nano -w /etc/default/grub           
update-grub
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot

nano -w /etc/fstab 
----
/dev/sda1            /boot      vfat    defaults,noatime 0 2
/dev/sda2            /          ext4    noatime 0 1
----

adduser l3gi0n
addgroup l3gi0n adm
addgroup l3gi0n sudo

passwd root

exit

reboot
```

I am getting this Kernel Panic: https://ibb.co/XFTKBtN

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu Base"?  Do you mean the cloud image base tarball which is not a complete version of Ubuntu (and therefore is used along with other components to 'spin' a VM from the base image)?

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/20.04/release/

Comment: That isn't a full install image.  It's designed for you to create custom container images, not deploy as a full VM.  [Read the Ubuntu Wiki regarding the Base tarball](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base).  It indicates you need the tarball AND the kernel for the "target device" AND the boot-loader for the "target device" - on its own it doesn't have what you need to spin an Ubuntu VM up.  You need to use one of the actual ISOs or such for that, normally, or some other mechanism of deployment that actually does all the steps and gets what you need 'installed' for the system to boot.